# Prove inequality bound for truncated random variables $X_{nk\delta}, X_{nk1}$

Tags: probability-theory

I need to prove a theorem from "The General Central Limit Theorem for Real and Banach valued random variables" (auth. E. Giné, A. Araujo) that gives necessary and sufficient conditions for weak convergence.

More specifically I need help proving the inequality below.

**The inequality:**

[image]

**Notation etc.**

- $0 < \delta < 1 $
- $ X_{nk1} = X_{nk} \ 1_{\{ X_{nk} \leq 1 \}} $
- $X_{nk\delta} =    X_{nk} \ 1_{\{ X_{nk} \leq \delta \}}$
- $\mu_{nk} = \mathcal{L}(X_{nk})$ $ \ \ \ $ *(the distribution of $X_{nk}$)*

**My initial computation:**

\begin{align*}
& \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{k=1}^{k_n} \bigg\vert \int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} (x-E[X_{nk1}])^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk1})(x)-\int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} (x-E[X_{nk\delta}])^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk\delta})(x)\bigg\vert \\[1em]
&= \sum_{k=1}^{k_n} \bigg\vert \int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk1})(x) + \int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} (E[X_{nk1}])^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk1})(x) \\[1em]
& \quad \quad \quad - 2\int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} xE[X_{nk1}] d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk1})(x)- \int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk\delta})(x) \\[1em]
& \quad \quad \quad - \int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} (E[X_{nk\delta}])^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk\delta})(x) + 2\int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} xE[X_{nk\delta}] d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk\delta})(x) \bigg\vert\\[1em]
&= \sum_{k=1}^{k_n} \bigg\vert \int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk})(x)-2E[X_{nk1}]\int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk})(x) + \mu_{nk}([-\delta,\delta])(E[X_{nk1}])^2 - \int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk})(x)-\mu_{nk}([-\delta,\delta])(E[X_{nk\delta}])^2 + 2E[X_{nk\delta}]\int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk})(x) \bigg\vert \\[1em]
\end{align*}

*Thoughts:* Now I can't quite see how to go from here. It also puzzles me quite a bit that I need the complements $[-1,1]^c,[-\delta,\delta]^c $ somehow. At some point we will probably use the triangle inequality and pull out max from the sums. Am I on the right track and if so can anyone help me finish the computation?

Comment: Aren't you missing some cross terms when squaring $x-E[X_{nk1}]$ and $x-E[X_{nk\delta}]$ in the second line?

Comment: I don't believe so. I am basically just using the same as the variance formula $E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$

Comment: Maybe everything cancels out, but the way I thought you arrived at the second line was by squaring $x- E[X_{nk1}]$ inside the integrand, and then distributing. So that the first term is $\int x^2 d\mathcal{L}-2 \int x E[X_{nk1}]d\mathcal{L} + \int (E[X_{nk1}])^2d\mathcal{L}$. It seems that cross term is related the last term but I'm not sure.

Comment: You might be right actually, I have changed the computation

Comment: Notice at this point that, for example in the first term, in order to to get $E(X_{nk}^2)$, you have to add the part of the integral back when $|x|>\delta$. When you start adding and subtracting that stuff you will start getting the measures of the complement popping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer, but at least I have a comment that I think goes most of the way. A simple version of this problem is when $X_{nk}$ is symmetric and supported on $[-1,1]$, so that $E(X_{nk})= E(X_{nk1}) = E(X_{nk\delta})=0$, and $X_{nk} = X_{nk1}$ in which case the problem reduces to (when $k_n=1$)

$$\bigg\vert \int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk})(x)-\int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk\delta})(x)\bigg\vert \le 2 \delta \mu_{nk}[-\delta, \delta]^c. $$

Intuitively $\int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk\delta})(x)>  \int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk})(x)$, since the law of $X_{nk\delta}$ puts more mass on subsets of $[-\delta, \delta]$. Also, for any measurable subset $A$ of $[-\delta, \delta]$, $\mu_{nk\delta}(A) - \mu_{nk}(A) \le \mu_{nk}([-\delta,\delta]^c)$ (expand $\mu_{nk\delta}(A)$ as a sum of two terms depending on whether $X_{nk} \in [-\delta,\delta]$). Use this fact and the definition of the integral to get the bound in this simple case.

Comment: How do you prove $\int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk\delta})(x)>  \int _{\{ \vert x \vert \leq \delta \}} x^2 d\mathcal{L}(X_{nk})(x)$?

Comment: @CruZ, notice that for any subset $A \subset [-\delta,\delta]$, $P( X_{nk\delta} \in A) >P( X_{nk} \in A)$. Hence the intergral of every simple function approximating $\int_{\{|x|< \delta\}} x^2 dX_{nk\delta}$ is larger than that corresponding to  $\int_{\{|x|< \delta\}} x^2 dX_{nk }$.